# Kubernetes-plugin: Contradiction in containerTemplate inheritance

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blame/master/README.md#L214-L226

I'm not understanding the inheritance behavior. In the container templates section, it mentions that it inherits the parent template with the same name. But going down the readme, it mentions that overriding a previously created (I'm assuming that it is the parent?) container template image with the same name is possible.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like 2 different things.

- One is the inheritance from a parent of the same name. If no values for image, etc are specified then it will inherit from the parent.
- The other is overriding an image name from a parent where it's inheriting from. So if the parent has `image: mycontainer1` and the inheriting template has `image: mycontainer2`, then `mycontainer2` will be used. If you are using exactly the same image with the same tag then the point of overring is moot.

Comment: sorry as I'm new to this, so does that mean that a (child?) template will only inherit from the parent if there is not (etc image) value? And that if there is a value in the child, it would just override it?

Comment: It could inherit other values that are not 'image' if you are not overriding those for example.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation, and this info confirms that our system is not working as expected. Our team is using the deprecated containerTemplate{} format and the values are not being overridden, do you happen to know if the deprecation might have caused the overriding behavior to be lost?

Comment: After testing different ways of building, I am happy to report that it wasn't containerTemplate{} that was causing the overriding behavior to be lost, but the way our team is handling passing the variable to the podTemplate. Thanks again Rico! Your explanation cleared up some things for me.